# Ho to mark java task as Failed

Tags: java, javafx, task

In my JavaFx application I send a request to a server and need to wait for a result.

Here is the code which executes a request:

```
private void getData(){
        RequestExecutor requestExecutor = new RequestExecutor();

        Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });


        Task<JSONObject> jsonObjectTask = new Task<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public JSONObject call() throws Exception {
                return requestExecutor.getObjectFromJsonArray("settings");
            }
        };

        jsonObjectTask.stateProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                statusLabel.setText(jsonObjectTask.getValue().getString("subnet"));
            } else if (newState == Worker.State.FAILED) {
                statusLabel.setText("Incorrect");
            }
        });

        exec.execute(jsonObjectTask);
    }
```

And

```
requestExecutor.getObjectFromJsonArray("settings")
```

returns a json object or null in case of connection failure.

I'd like to show a dialog for a user in order to ask him to retry again in case if no server connection etc.

How can I mark the task as failed? Or what is the best practrice to update GUI in case of requests failures?

Comment: Why not just test for `jsonObjectTask.getValue() == null` in the listener? (It would probably be better to have `requestExecutor.getObjectFromJsonArray(...)` throw an exception in the case of a connection failure; then you could let that exception propagate through the `call()` method and just handle that case in the `newState==FAILED` case in the listener. I don't know if you have control over the implementation of that method.)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for! I am not familiar with JavaFX and tasks enough yet.